# Blogger: getting the featured image to show up in the header

Tags: blogger

I have this code snippet that works, that I use to get and show the featured image of a post. However, when I place it in the header, outside the #Blog1 widget, it does not work. Is there a way to get it to work?

```
<a class='featured-image-link' expr:id='("featured-image-link" + data:i)' expr:href='data:post.url'/>
    <b:with value='data:post.featuredImage ?: "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-_bZMj71nEGc/Xij1Et5dzPI/AAAAAAAAgBg/iq5xmgI-DqkegOXEBiFbh6xdFcGmBP39QCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/default-image-dark_1920x1080.png"' var='featuredImg'>
    <b:include data='{ image: data:featuredImg, selector: ("#featured-image-link" + data:i) }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
</b:with>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through blog posts.
**But** outside Blog widget, you can only get post featured image, title and id. So post url won't work.

```xml
<b:loop index='i' values='data:widgets.Blog.first.posts' var='post'>

  <b:with value='data:post.featuredImage ?: "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-_bZMj71nEGc/Xij1Et5dzPI/AAAAAAAAgBg/iq5xmgI-DqkegOXEBiFbh6xdFcGmBP39QCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/default-image-dark_1920x1080.png"' var='featuredImg'>
    <b:include data='{ image: data:featuredImg, selector: ("#featured-image-link" + data:i) }' name='responsiveImageStyle'/>
  </b:with>

</b:loop>
```